# SPLUNK subsearch 2 CSV Files join together

Tags: computer-vision, splunk, spl

I have 2 Files with order data saved in two different sourcetypes in splunk.
One file contains an orderid, plnum(praefix + orderid (one ordernumer contains 3 plnum)), model (type of the order). The second file contains the same plnum's and Materialnumbers to those plnum's.

I want to search for the top Materials used for one or more Models.

So I searched for how to setup a subsearch:

```
sourcetype=file1 [search sourcetype=file2 MODEL="someting"| fields MODEL] |stats values(MATNR) by MODEL
```

I dont know why the subsearch dont work.

Comment: sorry i want to write [...]fields PLNUM] stats values(MATNR) by PLNUM

Answer (score 0):

Run the subsearch by itself to verify it works and produces the expected results.  I suspect it is working and is returning a list of PLNUMs in the form `foo bar baz...`.  Splunk puts an implicit `AND` between search terms so your main search is looking for events containing all PLNUMs, which is unlikely.

Try using `format` in your subsearch.  It returns the results in `foo OR bar OR baz...` format, which should work better in the main search.

`sourcetype=file1 [search sourcetype=file2 MODEL="someting"| fields PLNUM | format] |stats values(MATNR) by PLNUM`

Comment: thanks I think this works, IM not fure because of what probalby because of the |format.